# EasyMock test case failed saying method called incorrectly

Tags: unit-testing, junit, easymock

Does anyone know what the numbers 5b40c281 and 78a1d1f4 mean in the EasyMock test case fail shown below?

Are they essentially address pointers to two different instances of PdlPrintJob?

Does anyone know why this fail is occurring?

In the main code, PdlPrintJob is constructed (using new PdlPrintJob()) and passed as a parameter to method printer.executePrintJob().

In the test case, PdlPrintJob is constructed (using new PdlPrintJob()) and passed as a parameter to mockPrinter.executePrintJob().

Thanks for any advice,

Best regards

James

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:
Unexpected method call executePrintJob(com.canon.cel.meap.jobs.PdlPrintJob@5b40c281, EasyMock for interface com.canon.meap.security.AccessControlToken):
executePrintJob(com.canon.cel.meap.jobs.PdlPrintJob@5b40c281, EasyMock for interface com.canon.meap.security.AccessControlToken): expected: 0, actual: 1
executePrintJob(com.canon.cel.meap.jobs.PdlPrintJob@78a1d1f4, EasyMock for interface com.canon.meap.security.AccessControlToken): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

Comment: It because the object instances are not same, you are not sending the mocked object as param, you are creating a new object instead. Just check about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: Are you correctly implementing `PdlPrintJob.equals()`

Comment: We probably also need to see the actual test code with your expectations

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have done something like this in your test class.

```
EasyMock.expect(executePrintJob(new PdlPrintJob(),....))'
```

but actually it should have been a mockObject that you should have passed as parameter.

you need to do something like this

```
PdlPrintJob pdlPrintJob=Easymock.createNiceMock(PdlPrintJob.class);
Powermock.expectNew(PdlPrintJob).andReturn(pdlPrintJob).anyTimes(); //this will return the mocked instance of PDlPrintJob class wherever 'new' operator is used for this class
EasyMock.expect(executePrintJob(pdlPrintJob,.....)).andReturn(anythingYouWantToReturn).anyTimes(); // have added '.....' in case there are other parameters to this method
EasyMock.replay(pdlPrintJob);
Powermock.replayAll();
```

You were facing the issue because Easymock is a strict mocking framework, you had asked it to expect a particular method with particular object type only `(its like tightly binding method expectation to a single object)`, and during execution as new operator was used the method expectation failed as object parameters didnt match the expectation of Easymock, resulting in this exception.

I always prefer doing something like this for method expectation

if my method to be tested is

```
public String compress(String str, Integer intr, double ch){}
```

I expect this method in easymock as follows:

```
EasyMock.expect(compress(EasyMock.anyObject(String.class),EasyMock.anyObject(Integer.class),EasyMock.anyDouble())).andReturn("Done compressing").anyTimes();
```

so by this approach my method expectation works for any valid parameters passed to my compress() method during test case execution.

Hope that helps!

Good luck!

Comment: if passing mock to method expectation doesnt work, you can try second approach, it definitely works!